# Android Memory Managment: Engine as Singleton?

Tags: java, android, android-memory

I'm going through some memory issues with my Android development.

I was wondering if my actual model would work, and also would like some input on *how* to do this in a better way:

- I need `public static final` **globals**
- I need `public` **global variables** that never gets garbage collected
- I need to have an **Engine** running and never destroy without me calling `stop()`

```
MainApplication : Application
  public static final Boolean DEBUG = false;
  onCreate()
    Engine.getEngine().prepare()

  MainActivity : Activity
    onResume()
      Engine.getEngine().start()
    onPause()
      Engine.getEngine().stop()

Engine
  prepare()
    MainApplication.DEBUG = true;
  start()
    LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates()
  stop()
    LocationManager.removeUpdates()
```

Engine is a Singleton class, receiving location updates and such.

It is imperative that my Engine class does  not get released not the DEBUG variable.

Comment: Have you considered using "Shared Preferences" and a Service (**not** the same as a Windows-Service in Android!)?

Comment: SharedPreferences are too limited. The `Boolean DEBUG` is an (stupid) simple example.

Comment: OK, I see. But for the public static final vars: how are they set? Are they constants or are they set in a static init-block? Besides: "public static final" is not really that "variable" ;)

Comment: (list items) 1 are set in code (basic stuff). 2 are set by Engine.prepare() after heavy operations. 3. is my Engine singleton

Comment: OK, the basic stuff could be collected in one public Class that contains nothing else than declarations in the form of `public static final boolean/String/whatever MYCONSTANT = ConstVal;` Lazy set ones are somewhat more difficult. For the Engine , I'd recommend using a [Service](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html).

Comment: @Fildor Could I safelly put my type variable 2 in a Service? If so, please post an answer :)

Comment: Just thought the same. The service is accessible globally and it can provide getters. The other way would be to use a SQLite database. (That's easier than it sounds!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- For your "Type 1" constants use a dedicated public class containing `public static final T NAME = Val;` - declarations.
- For the Engine, I'd recommend using a Service.
- For your "Type 2" vars, the [Service](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) could offer getters **or** you could make use of [SQLite](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db).

I see there's some "Location"-Stuff going on there ... the developer website has some good "best practices" on using the Location Services. Maybe there you'll get some more inspiration.